# docker unable to load stylesheets for laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I created a very small and simple docker-compose for a small test with laravel. About everything works apart from that I am unable to get my stylesheets to load. It works perfectly locally in valet.

here is my docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/web.docker
        ports:
            - 8080:80
            - 9090:8080
       links:
            - app
            - mariadb
    app:
        build:
             context: ./
            dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/app.docker
        volumes:
            - ~/workbench/laravel/testproject:/var/www/testproject
        depends_on:
          - mariadb
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.2
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
            MYSQL_DATABASE: testproject
            TEST_DB_NAME: laravel_test
            MYSQL_USER: laravel
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: laravel
            MARIADB_DATABASE: testproject
        volumes:
            - ./mariadb:/var/mariadb
        ports:
            - 33061:3306
```

Here is my vhost for nginx

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php;
root /var/www/testproject/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I can visit all my routes, and functions seem to work just fine, it's just that none of my javascript, images or stylesheets are loading.
For example I try to load a bootstrap from a template like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/homer/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Inside my public folder I do have the whole directory /public/homer/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css the file is located at the correct directory.

Am I missing something that I have to do inside the vhost to make sure that those files can be loaded just fine?

I have tried to edit the path from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/homer/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/homer/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

and any form of public.

- /public/
- public
- ../../../../public

but none seem to work. I also rather not have to change this so my path can just remain the same between docker and valet.

Comment: I guess you need first to copy the css to your public dir, with ```php artisan asset:publish vendor/package```

Comment: As stated my stylesheets are inside my public directory, they are not part of a package that I need to publish.

Comment: Sorry for that! Can you try ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('afer_public_path/bootstrap.css'}}" />``` ?

Comment: I have managed to find the problem as per my answer below. Your solution sadly didn't work either when I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperantly I had to add the index server.php into my vhost.conf so it will look as follow:

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php server.php;
root /var/www/testproject/public;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
}
```

However I am still unsure how this works since I set the root inside the public folder which only has a index.php. The server.php only loads the index.php, am I missing something here on how nginx index work?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but today I have face the same issue and fixed it by adding same `volumes` option to **web** service. After this nginx able to look for the  **public** directory and find all your asset files in that directory.

```
volumes:
    - ~/workbench/laravel/testproject:/var/www/testproject
```

If you did not provide volumes option in **web** service docker will not map files to container and there will be no files in `/var/www/testproject` directory and thus files can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Laravel's built in `asset()` method that automatically prepends the host to your `public` folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}" />
```

*Note:* you may have to use Mix to move your `bootstrap` folder into 
 the `public` directory, or just do it yourself.